# classpath problem in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, classpath

Below is the snippet of Batch file

```
set CLASSPATH=%    CLASSPATH%;D:\BatchApps\RDev\RTesting\GRTesting_Config.properties.;D:\BatchApps\RDev\RTesting\log4j.properties

c:\progra~1\java\jre6\bin\java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar  D:\BatchApps\RDev\GRTesting\GRTesting.jar
```

GRTesting.jar is executable jar. So, when I run this batch file, I am getting properties file not found exception that is java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException

Anybody has an Idea?

Comment: u don't accept answers. you scare me =/

Answer (score 1):

First off you should not use the CLASSPATH environment variable, it causes too much trouble. Use the `-cp` parameter for java.exe instead.

Having said that: when using `-jar` any classpath defined through `-cp` or CLASSPATH is ignored.

You need to start your application using

```
SET CP = ....
SET CP=%cp%;D:\BatchApps\RDev\GRTesting\GRTesting.jar

java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -cp %CP% your.MainClass
```

**Edit**: I don't think you can add .properties files like that directly. I think you need to add the *directory* containing the property files, not the files themselves:

```
SET cp=D:\BatchApps\RDev\GRTesting\GRTesting.jar;D:\BatchApps\RDev\RTesting
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -cp %CP% your.MainClass
```

Comment: Still I am getting this:  Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name GRTesting_Config, locale en_US

Comment: See my edit, you need to specify the directories if I'm not mistaken

Comment: no, I do not think so.. I have another batch file from different application that works with CLASSPATh instead using CP..hence confused.